# public abstract class Hand implements Comparable<Hand> , Serializable{

Tags: android

If Hand is self defined abstract class , then it implements itself as template? it doesn't make too sense.  what's your take on the above declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From docs.oracle.com:

"It is possible, however, to define a class that does not implement all of the interface methods, provided that the class is declared to be abstract."

The declaration you have only names two interfaces: Comparable, and Serializable. Since Hand is an abstract class, it doesn't have to actually implement those interfaces, but any non-abstract class that extends Hand must do so.

The page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html has more good info/explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If class implements some generic interface, passing itself as parameter, it means the class implements some methods with itself as parameter. So in case of `Comparable` it tells, that class MUST have method `compareTo` to compare itself with another instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Makes sense to me. It means that you can compare two hands.